# Apple ID with iCloud email vs non-Apple email, any differences in capabilities?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I'm about to create a new account with Apple's cloud services. AFAIK there are two ways to go:

1. Create a 'full' new iCloud account from an Apple device, thus creating a new email address ending in @icloud.com at the same time.
2. 'Just' create an Apple ID using a non-Apple email address I already have, i.e. a GMail or Outlook or other existing email.

An @icloud.com email gives me native integration with the Apple mail & calendar & contacts clients on macOS and iOS, and generally uses push data for synchronization.

Both options might require migrating some existing emails or data, depending on the situation.

My question is, beyond the native Mail, Calendar & Contacts app integrations, are there any other **differences between an @icloud.com Apple ID and a 'non-Apple mail' Apple ID?** Any gotchas down the road, like some security or health related synch services not working with non-iCloud accounts, or less cloud space, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are there any other differences between an @icloud.com Apple ID and a 'non-Apple mail' Apple ID?

No. Both approaches give you a fully capable Apple ID. There's no different type of Apple IDs.

> Any gotchas down the road, like some security or health related synch services not working with non-iCloud accounts, or less cloud space, or...?

No, nada. Any Apple ID created using whatsoever approach is similar in capabilities and security.

**Note**: A difference that I noticed: I attempted to create an Apple ID using a 3rd-party email and created it via [Web](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204316#web). You only get 1 GB of iCloud storage.